# Preprocessor Directive Issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, preprocessor-directive

I am trying to include Google+ api and foursquare api in my ios app. When compiling it shows lexical or preprocessor issue caused because both are using `#define DEBUG` statement that is conflicting while compiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question I am not sure, but I can sense, some code part is missing...

So you can try this one:

Comment or remove those lines and compile again.

Or It can be converted to

```
#ifdef DEBUG
  NSLog(@"log");
#endif
```

EDIT:

As you changed your question, now it is clear what is the error.

Remove one `#define DEBUG` from either of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Or to be on the save side/more flexible in your code, do:

```
#ifndef DEBUG
   #define DEBUG
#endif
```

But this is probably not a 100% good idea, because it would affect all your build configurations. (Which may not be desired)